# Can't build with using this "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager" in android 4.4.2

Tags: android, eclipse

I have some code where I have to use ViewPager from android support library v4.

I've used it as following:

```
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

I have also used **android 4.4.2** to build my application.

My application java build path is as following:

[image]

But, this give me delvik exception.
When I try with unchecked the support library it give

```
01-03 09:10:10.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2721): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.ClockPackage$TabsAdapter
```

Can anyone please provide any solution for it. I have used eclipse for code build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably if your `dalvik exception` is multiple dex file you have already that support library somewhere else on your project (maybe on third party libraries) , you have to remove one of them.

Comment: from the console I got this:
[2014-07-16 12:43:59 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter;
[2014-07-16 12:43:59 - ClockPackage] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter;

Comment: I also need to use android support library v13 for fragmentpager

Comment: @MustakimurRahman : so the answer is right, you have two android.support.v4 in your project. if you have libraries which contains android.support.v4 in their lib folder just keep one of them and remove the other.